# Why is Windows is still caching failed DNS queries even after editing the registry?

Tags: windows-7, windows, dns, windows-registry, cache

Throughout the day, my 3G modem will sometimes disconnect and reconnect instantaneously. If I happen to request a webpage at the exact moment the modem disconnects, Windows will cache the failed query and I can't visit that page without executing `ipconfig /flushdns`.

I have to do this about 20 times a day and it's extremely annoying. I edited the registry to disable caching failed DNS queries:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Dnscache\Parameters
Name: NegativeCacheTime
Value: 0 (DWORD)
```

This seemed to work for a few days, but now Windows is caching them again. I've checked the registry and the value of `NegativeCacheTime` has not changed.

What's going on here?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to turn on a flashlight with your nose. Fix the 3G modem is what I would do.

Comment: There's nothing I can do about the 3G modem. It's a side effect of using mobile broadband in a rural area. Unfortunately, it's the only broadband I have access to. The reconnect is usually unnoticeable anyway, aside from the problem I outlined here, which is a Windows issue.